# Issue with Shape in Python Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, reshape

I have the following dataframe: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markamcgown/Projects/master/df_model.csv

At "---> 11 history = model.fit" in the last block of code below, I get the error "ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_8 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 26]"

**Why is it expecting a minimum of 3 dimensions and how can I automate my code below to always have the right shape?**

```
import keras
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Bidirectional
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Reshape, GlobalAveragePooling1D

path = r'C:\Users\<your_local_directory>\df_model.csv'
#Import raw data file with accelerometer data
df_model = pd.read_csv(path)
df_model
```

[image]

```
y_column = 'Y_COLUMN'
x = df_model.drop(y_column, inplace=False, axis=1).values
y = df_model[y_column].values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
```

```
def create_model(num_features, num_classes, dropout=0.3,
                loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer="rmsprop"):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(100, 10, activation='relu', input_shape=(None,num_features)))
    model.add(Conv1D(100, 10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
    model.add(Conv1D(160, 10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv1D(160, 10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(LSTM(160, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(160, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=loss, metrics=["mean_absolute_error"], optimizer=optimizer)
    return model
```

```
DROPOUT = 0.4
LOSS = "huber_loss"
OPTIMIZER = "adam"

num_time_periods, num_features = x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1]

model = create_model(num_features, num_classes=len(set(df_model[y_column])), loss=LOSS, 
                      dropout=DROPOUT, optimizer=OPTIMIZER)
```

```
callbacks_list = [keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5',monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True),keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=1)]

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Hyper-parameters
BATCH_SIZE = 400
EPOCHS = 1

# Enable validation to use ModelCheckpoint and EarlyStopping callbacks.
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,epochs=EPOCHS,callbacks=callbacks_list,validation_split=0.2,verbose=1)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 4))
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], "g-", label="Training Accuracy")
#plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], "g", label="Accuracy of validation data")
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], "r-", label="Training Loss")
#plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], "r", label="Loss of validation data")
plt.title('Model Performance')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy & Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylim(0)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The `input_shape` argument in `Conv1D` should not include the batch dimension. Try `input_shape=(num_features,)`

Comment: Good suggestion, jakub. That is the first thing I tried and it results in the same error. If you have time/insight, the file from my github is linked for this minimal case if you want to explore the code+error.

Comment: The [documentation for `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D) says that Conv1D is a temporal convolution and takes inputs of `(batch, timesteps, features)`. You might want to use a Dense layer instead of Conv1D.

Comment: What does the data represent? Are A-Z different accelerometer features (directions / magnitudes?) with each row representing a sequential timestep? If so I would question if your random train_test_split is the best approach. Or are A-Z sequential readings?